# Laravel 4 displaying flash message doesn't work

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to display some flash messages, after I have successfully logged in. Can somebody help me understand why nothing is shown ?? Although I know the Session is true?`

This is my Sessions Controller:

```
 class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('sessions.create');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $attempt = Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => $input['password']
        ]);

        if($attempt) return Redirect::intended('/')->with('flash_message', 'You have been logged in!');

        dd('problem');
    }



    public function destroy()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::home();
    }

}
```

And here is my view where the message should be displayed:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        @if(Session::get('flash_message'))
            <div class="flash">
                {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried this:

```
        @if(Session::get('flash_message'))
            <div class="flash">
                {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
            </div>
        @else 
            <div class="flash">
                {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
            </div>
        @endif
```

But nothing get's displayed, just an empty nothingness, just like no message was parsed to the view.

Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Even this question is old, I will add this comment. For the IF condition you have to use 'has()' method instead of get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `store` function, before `if` you should add:

```
Session::flash('flash_message', 'You have been logged in!');
```

This is used to store flash data in session. The `with` method won't work in a way you intend.

And then in view:

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
@endif
```

Comment: It's weird, because in Jeffrey Way's Video it works exactly as he describes. Do you have an explanation for this? 
http://youtu.be/msEwmVZ4wp4?t=11m36s